# How to consider data attribute in Jsoup doc.select()?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I am searching for webpage links using

```
Elements elements = doc.select("a");
```

and I get the result only if the element's code is `<a href="/example"`. And when the code is `<a data-v-1234567a href="/example2"` then "elements" is empty, nothing is found.

So should all links be found if I'm using `Elements elements = doc.select("a");` or should I consider data attribute specifically (what should I do then)?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample HTML you are trying to extract the links from? What you have shared so far is an invalid markup and jsoup tries its best to magically correct it. [As you can see](https://try.jsoup.org/~z-w-7_oMmEbli0k8slPIKWJXioQ), the result of this process is not necessarily what you would expect.

Comment: yes, my examples were rather bad, here are the real ones:
 1) I can find this href: <a href="/login" class="header__buttons"> Login</a>
 2) But I cannot find this href: <a data-v-12345="" href="/restore" class="footer" data-v-54321=""> forgot password? </a>

Comment: I don't see a problem. Both of those links can be queried using the selector `a`: [example](https://try.jsoup.org/~N5r23r2-p3py6LAZsxR2_fXhxUM).